# Eloquent laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a project and I want to do it, but I got a problem in relationships.

*Project Details:*
The system consists of a set of *courses*, each course offered by one or more *trainers*, and each *trainee* can enroll in one or more courses.

*My question :*
How do I make relationships in Laravel? So that I can get all courses of the trainee with the course information and the trainer who provided the course.

Comment: If you want to build it, what's stopping you? What is your question?

Comment: You must have mistaken Stackoverflow for Codefactory. I'm pretty sure this is not how it works.

Comment: * Project Details: *
The system consists of a set of *courses*, each course offered by one or more *trainers*, and each *trainee* can enroll in one or more courses.

* My question : *
How do I make relationships in Laarval? So that I can get all courses of the trainee with the course information and the trainer who provided the course

Answer (score 0):

> My question : How do I make relationships in Laravel?

Laravel uses eloquent to define models and relationships.

In your case, i think you are looking for a **One to Many** and **Many to Many** relationship:

- Course has many traniners
- Trainee belongs to many courses
- Course belongs to many trainees

*TIP*: In **Many to Many** relationship is needed a third table with both primary key.

Just look the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships